# Faster way to store an org link to an identifier in a projectile project?

Tags: org-mode, projectile, org-link, ag

I'm trying to come up with a faster workflow for storing org-file links to parts of a source code tree. I'm generally starting in my org file taking notes, doing a `helm-ag` to search for some function or variable, doing an `org-store-link` from the found file, going back to the org file and then doing an `org-insert-link`.

While this works, it feels a bit clunky. I'm wondering if I can do this perhaps straight from the helm session - `helm-find-files` provides a 'Insert as Org Link' (`helm-ff-run-insert-org-link`). Is there a library or something else that provides a similar feature for `helm-ag` (or for other search buffers)?